# DataStax: Compaction on rollups60 table, making DSE service to do down

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We have DSE 5.0.7 on 3 node cluster. For last 2 days once the compaction on rollups60 table starts DSE service stops. Don't see any errors in the log files.
Job takes several hours and DSE service goes down couple of times.

Can you please help if we can control the compaction job so that we can schedule it during off peak time?

Comment: Please add more details about your setup, amount of data, etc.

Comment: 2.5 GB for opscenter keyspace. Total data size 75GB.
3 nodes. Each node 14cores, 50 GB memory. Please let me know if you need any more details.